I want to add chart in django for blog
I want to add a chart in django blog using tinymce and I also use plugin but it doesnt work.
I add this plugin in static/tinymce/plugins/chart_plugin/plugin.min.js file
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#chart-result',
  height: 550,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste',
    'highcharts highchartssvg noneditable'
  ],
  toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image'
});

and I aslo add default conf in settings.py file:
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    "entity_encoding": "raw",
    'menubar': True,
    'plugins': '''
        textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
        table code lists fullscreen insertdatetime nonbreaking
        contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
        visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists charmap print hr
        anchor pagebreak chart_plugin
    ''',
    "toolbar": "fullscreen preview | undo redo | bold italic forecolor backcolor | formatselect | image link | "
    "alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist checklist | fontsizeselect "
    "emoticons | ",
    'width': '70%',
    'height': 700,
    "custom_undo_redo_levels": 50,
    "quickbars_insert_toolbar": False,
    "file_picker_callback": """function (cb, value, meta) {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "file");
        if (meta.filetype == "image") {
            input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
        }
        if (meta.filetype == "media") {
            input.setAttribute("accept", "video/*");
        }

        input.onchange = function () {
            var file = this.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function () {
                var id = "blobid" + (new Date()).getTime();
                var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                var base64 = reader.result.split(",")[1];
                var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                blobCache.add(blobInfo);
                cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        };
        input.click();
    }""",
    "content_style": "body { font-family:Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }",
}

But it doesnt work
